# Rename files based on values from a DB

Tags: mysql, perl, rename

I am very new to Perl and I need to complete a project that is going to rely on it. I need to take pictures that are in a folder, look up their name in a DB and then rename the picture based on another value in that row.

So say I need to rename the picture

```
010300000000001002.jpg
```

I need to then have the script look in the db for

```
010300000000001002
```

in the `USERID`. Then when it finds the match I need it to look for the `EMPNUM` value in the same row. Then take the `EMPNUM` value and rename the picture to that value.jpg, which in this case equals 1002. So the end product would end up like this:

```
Old Picture: 010300000000001002.jpg
New Picture: 1002.jpg
```

Then repeat for all of the pictures in that folder.

Read from the DB Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use DBI;
# Replace datasource_name with the name of your data source.  AdventureWorksDW \dbo.DimEmployee
# Replace database_username and database_password
# with the SQL Server database username and password.
my $data_source = q/not giving the data source/;
my $user = q/Not giving the user/;
my $password = q/Not Giving the password /;
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $password)
    or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";

# Catch and display status messages with this error handler.
sub err_handler {
   my ($sqlstate, $msg, $nativeerr) = @_;
   # Strip out all of the driver ID stuff
   $msg =~ s/^(\[[\w\s:]*\])+//;
   print $msg;
   print "===> state: $sqlstate msg: $msg nativeerr: $nativeerr\n";
   return 0;
}

$dbh->{odbc_err_handler} = \&err_handler;

$dbh->{odbc_exec_direct} = 1;

# Prepare your sql statement (perldoc DBI for much more info).
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select userid, empnum from dbo.emp0');

# Execute the statement.
if ($sth->execute)
{
    # This will keep returning until you run out of rows.
    while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        print "ID = $row->{userid}, Name = $row->{empnum}\n";
    }
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Copy and rename file script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;
my @old_names = glob "/root/pics/*.jpg";


foreach my $old_name (@old_names) {

    my $new_name = "picture$i" . ".jpg";

    rename($old_name, "/root/pics/$new_name") or die "Couldn't rename $old_name to $new_name: $!\n";

} continue { $i++ }

print "Pictures have been renamed.\n";
```

Edit:
This is what I ended up with and it does the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::Copy;
use DBI;

my $data_source = q/db/;
my $user = q/user/;
my $password = q/password/;
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $password)
    or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";

# Catch and display status messages with this error handler.
sub err_handler {
   my ($sqlstate, $msg, $nativeerr) = @_;
   # Strip out all of the driver ID stuff
   $msg =~ s/^(\[[\w\s:]*\])+//;
   print $msg;
   print "===> state: $sqlstate msg: $msg nativeerr: $nativeerr\n";
   return 0;
}
$dbh->{odbc_err_handler} = \&err_handler;
$dbh->{odbc_exec_direct} = 1;

sub move_image 
{
    my $user_id = $_[0];
    my $emp_num = $_[1];

    my $old_name = "/root/picS/${user_id}.jpg";

    my $new_name = "/root/picD/${emp_num}.jpg";

    move($old_name, $new_name) or return 0;

    return 1;
}

# Prepare your sql statement (perldoc DBI for much more info).
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select userid, empnum from dbo.emp0');

# Execute the statement.
if ($sth->execute)
{
    # This will keep returning until you run out of rows.
    while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        my $user_id = $row->{userid};
        my $emp_num = $row->{empnum};

        if (move_image($user_id, $emp_num))
        {
            print "Moved image $user_id to $emp_num successfully\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "Could not move image $user_id to $emp_num successfully\n";
        }
    }
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: Just a note the example I've given is a bad example. The EMPNUM is at the end of the USERID value. This is not the case for 90% of the pictures that need to be changed.

Comment: Well so far I have a few separate scripts, the first just connects to the DB to test the connection. The second connects to the DB, and displays the values I need. The third recursively renames pictures as a test. Like I said I am completely new to Perl. I made these scripts to try out the different parts pf the script. I wanted to learn how to connect and read from the DB, and rename pictures. I guess I am trying to tie this all together now.

Comment: How do I bring those to scripts together to complete my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would suggest using `move` From [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html). The [rename subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) has restrictions on when it can be used. However, if you are certain that both images will always be in the same folder, then `rename` should be fine and may even be more efficient.

Add the following to the top of your code to be able to use `File::Copy`:

```
use File::Copy;
```

Second, if you want to integrate the functionality here, I would make the "move" code into a subroutine.

```
sub move_image 
{
    my $user_id = $_[0];
    my $emp_num = $_[1];

    my $old_name = "/root/pics/${user_id}.jpg";

    my $new_name = "/root/pics/picture${emp_num}.jpg";

    move($old_name, $new_name) or return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Then call the subroutine:

```
# This will keep returning until you run out of rows.
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
{
    my $user_id = $row->{userid};
    my $emp_num = $row->{empnum};

    if (move_image($user_id, $emp_num))
    {
        print "Moved image $user_id to $emp_num successfully\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Could not move image $user_id to $emp_num successfully\n";
    }
}
```

Just add the subroutine to your original script like I showed. Don't try to use two different scripts. [Subroutines](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) are very useful.

Comment: Thank you that helped a ton! Coming from Java a subroutine is just like a method. thanks again!

Comment: Glad that I could help! `Method` tends to be an Object-Oriented Programming term. It's just semantics, but you may want to read this: http://suite101.com/article/procedure--subroutine-or-function--a8208